# Hi i want to redirect from my actvity to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This my code to redirct from Viewactvity to Fragment_home (Fragment_Home,which is already used in my Mainactivity)

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Viewactivity.this,
                           Fragment_Home.class);

                    String responseMsg = jObj.getString("response");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            responseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("Your" + responseMsg);
             startActivity(intent);
```

My Fragment is Fragment_Home ,i didnt use Fragment manager  in the Viewactivity class,So can you please help me to navigate from my current activity to Fragment_Home.

Answer (score 2):

Fragment is not any activity that is contained in Activity, therefore you can add, replace, remove fragment there, not startActivity.

- you can start activity from fragment not fragment from activity.
- fragments are simply pushed in stack within an activity if required.
- you can also attach the fragment to your other activity in its live state(i.e. fragment is not removed so that its data can be used by your another activity)

check this for details:
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Yes i know That,But Fragment_home is already used in my Maniactvity.But now i want redirect From my another Activity to this Fragment.Is it possible ?? Can u pls give me some sample codes

Comment: check my updated answer and no way to start fragment in this way try to use it in another activity as your requirement. Thanks

Comment: when i try run the app it crashes ,showing the error as Unable to find explicit activity class {harico.groupdeallast/harico.groupdeallast.Fragments.Fragment_Home}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i have login page,so  my starting activity is loginactvity and i had already define it in android manifest